# "Hello World" app in Java FX with minimal Java code

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I selected Java FX between it and Swing because I want that view (*ML) and logic will be split (impossible in Swing).

Here is the "Hello world" template in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
 public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Two meddlings to View in the Logic part:

1. Setting title - `setTitle()`
2. Setting top-level element size: `primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));`.

Can I set same settings in FXML?

Answer (score 1):

The FXML loader will give you the root element, which already has a `prefWidth` and `prefHeight`.

You can't set the title but you can drop the size for the scene and it will be taken from the root element automatically.

Another thing that has to be set for the `Stage` explicitly are size constraints. You can have an initial size but the user can drag it around however he/she wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can set size using the

`prefHeight="yourHeightValue" prefWidth="yourWidthValue"`

sets in your scene's root element. You can create scenes using [SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) and it will generate related FXML for you.